# Trouble renaming files to customized names

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, file-rename

Can't rename old files located in a folder in desktop. There are three files there `item.pdf`,`item1.pdf` and `item2.pdf`. What I wish to do now is rename those files to `new_item.pdf`,`new_item1.pdf` and `new_item2.pdf`.

I tried with the below script:

```
import os

filepath = "/Users/WCS/Desktop/all_files/"

for item in os.listdir(filepath):
    os.rename(item,"new_name"+".pdf")
```

Executing the above script throws the following error. Whereas the folder address is accurate:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'item.pdf' -> 'new_name.pdf'
```

***How can I rename these three files `item.pdf`,`item1.pdf` and `item2.pdf` to `new_item.pdf`,`new_item1.pdf` and `new_item2.pdf` from a folder?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
import re

filepath = "/Users/WCS/Desktop/all_files/"

for item in os.listdir(filepath):
    match = re.search(r'\d+$', item)
    endnum = ""
    if match:
      endnum = match.group()
    os.rename(os.path.join(filepath, item), os.path.join(filepath, "new_name{}.pdf".format(endnum)))
```

or, if you don't wanna use `re`

```
import os

filepath = "/Users/WCS/Desktop/all_files/"

for item in os.listdir(filepath):
    new_name = item.replace('item', 'new_item')
    os.rename(os.path.join(filepath, item), os.path.join(filepath, "new_name{}.pdf".format(new_name)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either specify the full path to your file in `os.rename`.

Something like:

```
for item in filepath:
    os.rename(os.path.join(filepath, item), os.path.join(filepath, "new_item.pdf"))
```

Or change your current working directory to the directory where the files exist:

`os.chdir("/your/file/path")`

and then run your code.

See also https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename

Comment: No, never `chdir` while the script/program is in execution. It could save you a lot of time debugging. And be sane :)

Comment: True -- it might not be a good idea or best practice, but if you change your working directory to the directory where the files exist, you can indeed use `os.rename` without specifying the full file path. That's why I included it in my answer as an option.